# de structure json nested object

Tags: json, angular

I have the following json which are nested. I am looking for the better approach to read the data. Below is the sample json

```
    [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "some text",
    "selections": [
      {
        "id": 38383,
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "view",
            "children": [
              {
                "nodeId": "groups",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "nodeId": "groups 1",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "type": "group level item",
                        "name": "text1",
                        "leaf": true,
                        "info": [
                          "groups ",
                          "groups 1",
                          "groups 2"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "group level item",
                        "name": "text2",
                        "leaf": true,
                        "info": [
                          "groups ",
                          "groups 1",
                          "groups 2"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "some text",
    "selections": [
      {
        "id": 23232,
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "view",
            "children": [
              {
                "nodeId": "Hirearchy",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "nodeId": "Hirearchy level 1",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "nodeId": "Hirearchy level 2",
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "type": "charactreistic value",
                            "name": "some text 1",
                            "leaf": true,
                            "info": [
                              "Hirearchy",
                              "Hirearchy level 1",
                              "Hirearchy level 2",
                              "Hirearchy level 3"
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "type": "characterisitic value",
                            "name": "some text 2",
                            "leaf": true,
                            "info": [
                              "Hirearchy",
                              "Hirearchy level 1",
                              "Hirearchy level 2",
                              "Hirearchy level 3"
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "some text",
    "selections": [
      {
        "id": 2444,
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "view",
            "children": [
              {
                "nodeId": "category",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "type": "some value",
                    "name": "some text 1",
                    "leaf": true,
                    "info": [
                      "category",
                      "category level 1"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "some value",
                    "name": "some text 2",
                    "leaf": true,
                    "info": [
                      "category",
                      "category level 1"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "some text",
    "selections": [
      {
        "id": 2444,
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "view",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "some text",
    "selections": [
      {
        "id": 2444,
        "items": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "some text",
    "selections": []
  }
]
```

for id 1 - there is 3 levels of nesting and the last one has a property which says leaf = true. so in this i need to de structure the object to get the desire out put like

```
heading - group 2 (from info arrar)
name - ['text1', 'text2'] from the last leaf
```

for id 2 - there is 4 levels of nesting and the last one has a property which says leaf = true. so in this i need to de structure the object to get the desire out put like

```
   heading - Hierarchy level 3
   name - ['some text1', 'some text2']
```

for id 3 there is 2 levels of nesting and the last one has a property which says leaf = true. so i this
i need to se structure the object to get the desire output like this

```
   heading -  Category 1
   name - ['some text 3', 'some text4']



for id 4 - there is 1 level of nesting but the array is blank
for id 5 - there is no nesting and the items array is blank
for id 6 -  selections array is blank
```

Question 1. I need to write a generic method to loop thru the json object and find the node where the property 'leaf' is true.

Question 2. This generic method to work even if the nesting levels are 2 or 3 or 4 or it could be more also

Question 3. This generic method should not break the code when the array is empty also.

Requirement. this is required in angular 10 application where i need to destructure the object

Thanks in advance